# Finding shortest distance between two points with segments blocking

Tags: algorithm, geometry, graph-algorithm

I need to find the shortest Euclidean distance between endpoints `A, B` in the plane, subject to the constraint that there is a set of N segments `S=[S1,S2,...]` that my Euclidean path cannot intersect.

I can imagine a recursive approach that first "guesses" the straight line between `A,B`, and checks for any intersection with a segment `s`, changes the path to go around `s`, and then recursively calls the same algorithm on new endpoints. This would have runtime O(2^N) it seems like, since there are 2 ways to go around each segment.

This is a subproblem for a version of the Traveling Salesman Problem I am working on.

EDIT: If two segments share an endpoint, this point is passable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a graph `G` whose vertices are `A`, `B` and the `2N` endpoints of the segments.  Connect two points with an edge if and only if the straight line between them does not intersect any other edges.

Now use an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) to find the shortest path.